# use elasticsearch in gitlab-ci

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab-ci

I tried to use the elasticsearch service in gitlab -ci by adding:

```
image: python:3.6
services:
  - elasticsearch:2.4
```

in my .gitlab-ci.yml

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (I cannot a connection refused on http://127.0.0.1:9200/). Any idea?

I also tried to launch the docker image with:

```
test:
  script:
  - docker run -d elasticsearch
```

But `docker` is not present...

Comment: Have you tried with hostname `elasticsearch` (`http://elasticsearch:9200`)? See documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services

Comment: it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

For Elasticsearch 7, a working config looks like this:

```yaml
test-elasticsearch:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1"
      alias: "elasticsearch"
      command: [ "bin/elasticsearch", "-Expack.security.enabled=false", "-Ediscovery.type=single-node" ]
  script:
    - curl "http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health"
```

However, you can also have a look whether there is an embedded elasticsearch available for your runtime, e.g. for Java there are "testcontainers": https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch/. That way it's also easier to run tests locally for devs, since they don't need to worry about spinning up elasticsearch first.

Comment: Does anyone know what changed for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.0? It seems like the fix stopped working from that version and up.

Comment: I'm getting 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: elasticsearch wierd

Answer (score 9):

For those of you running rails apps using the searchkick gem, be sure to include the following in your `gitlab.ci.yml` file in addition to your other configurations. As mentioned by previous commenters, the hostname needs to be changed and the ELASTICSEARCH_URL environment variable is how you set it.

```
services:
  - elasticsearch:latest

variables:
  ELASTICSEARCH_URL "http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

And if you want to use the official elasticsearch image, you should be able to change the above to the following:

```
services:
  - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.0
    alias: elasticsearch

variables:
  ELASTICSEARCH_URL "http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

Answer (score 5):

For people coming here searching for a working example for elasticsearch 7.11 or higher:

elasticsearch 7.10.2 still has a Xmx and Xms in the config file, elasticsearch 7.11.0 has not.
So to fix this for 7.11 and higher, you need your CI file to look like this:

```
  services:
    - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.2
      alias: elastic
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - echo -Xms256m >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options && echo -Xmx256m >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch -Ediscovery.type=single-node
```

Without this, my kubernetes killed the container because it used too much memory.

Comment: Sir, I cannot tell you how much time you saved me with this information and with that command. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to set it up after following these instructions.

 
See the pipeline in action at https://git.drupalcode.org/project/data_pipelines/-/merge_requests/16/diffs#587d266bb27a4dc3022bbed44dfa19849df3044c_65_66

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer from @Pieter-Verloop, I needed to add something to wait for the Elasticsearch service to be ready on the default port of 9200. Gitlab has an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24197) where it does not know how to wait for services to be ready, sometimes.

My Gitlab CI file, in the most pared-down form I got it to, looks like this:

```
test-elasticsearch:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: elasticsearch:7.16.3
      command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch -Ediscovery.type=single-node
  script:
    - timeout 30 bash wait_for_service_up.sh elasticsearch:9200 || false
    - curl "http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health"
```

With a `wait_for_service_up.sh` script looking like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[
  "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' $1)" != "200"
]]; do
  sleep 5;
done
```

The end result of this is that the CI step will wait for up to 30 seconds for a curl to `elasticsearch:9200` to return a 200, which makes sure the service is ready before getting used in further work.

Answer (score 1):

TLTR;

*You might need to increase resources for ES container*

The long answer:

We use Kubernetes runners in our project.

We had similar problem - we couldn't connect with elastic service even the alias was set in the correct way.
We tried to use solutions from @bersling, @Pieter Verloop, @N N, @Jake Anderson without success.

After more debugging we found that the docker container started (`docker ps` in pipelines), but there were no logs (`./kubectl -n <namespace> logs <runner_pod_name> svc-0`).

Based on @Pieter Verloop answer we decided to check resources for the service (`./kubectl -n <namespace> describe pod <runner_pod_name>` and they were quite low.

```
    Init Containers:
      <pod_name>:
        Limits:
          cpu:     200m
          memory:  512Mi
        Requests:
          cpu:        100m
          memory:     256Mi
```

After the pod config update and with additional command from the @bersling answer it started working

values.yaml

```yaml
      config: |
        [[runners]]
          [runners.kubernetes]
            # ...
            # These values might be overkill for your project
            # Check metrics to get the correct amount for your project
            service_cpu_limit = "900m"
            service_memory_limit = "2.3Gi"
```

gitlab-ci.yaml

```yaml
      # ...
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch -Ediscovery.type=single-node
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use the "elasticsearch" hostname.
See here for hostnames depending o service used:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services
Thanks @jawad