# Gitlab Elasticsearch Service not connecting during pipeline run

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab-ci

We have managed to get both Mongo and PostgreSql working fine using Gitab service however we are facing real issues with elasticsearch.

Whenever we try to run the pipeline the connection to elastic fails.

I have tried the following steps in this thread: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/42214
But still no luck.

i.e. both

```
image: maven:latest

test:
  stage: test
services:
  - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
  alias: elasticsearch
  command: [ "bin/elasticsearch", "-Ediscovery.type=single-node" ]

  stage: test
  script:
  - ps aux
  - ss -plantu
  - curl -v "http://elasticsearch:9200/_settings?pretty"
```

and:

```
image: maven:latest

test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - elasticsearch:6.5.4
  script:
  - curl -v "http://127.0.0.1:9200/"
```

Result in connection errors.

Has anyone got this working for elasticsearch:6.5.4?

Comment: I was able to set it up after following the instructions from the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/70595301

 
See the pipeline in action at https://git.drupalcode.org/project/data_pipelines/-/merge_requests/16/diffs#587d266bb27a4dc3022bbed44dfa19849df3044c_65_66

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed by a 15 second sleep line. 
ci file now looks like:

```
test:
  stage: test
  services:
  - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
    command: ["bin/elasticsearch", "-Expack.security.enabled=false", "-Ediscovery.type=single-node"]
  script:
  - echo "Sleeping for 15 seconds.."; sleep 15;
```