# Elastic Search Service on Gitlab CI

Tags: python, elasticsearch, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373011/use-elasticsearch-in-gitlab-ci) and it works when my image is 7.17.2 but now that i have upgraded to version 8.0.0 of the elastic search, the connection is refused. Any leads on how to solve this?

```yaml
lint_and_test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgis/postgis:14-3.4
    - name: elasticsearch:8.0.0
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - echo -Xms256m >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options && echo -Xmx256m >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch -Ediscovery.type=single-node
  tags:
    - healthcloud-multi
  script:
    - timeout 60 bash wait_for_service_up.sh elasticsearch:9200 || false
    - curl "http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health"
```

I am trying to connect to a live Elastic search service for integration tests that depend on Elastic search.

Additionally, there is a Protocol Connection Error when I run locally as well which was not there prior to Elastic Search version 7. As per [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/migrating-8.0.html) docs , SSL certs are now required for elastic search 8 to use the transport interface and HTTP server, might that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Posting in case one might need it

```bash
    - name: elasticsearch:8.10.2
      alias: elasticsearch
      command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - >
          exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
          elasticsearch
          -Ediscovery.type=single-node
          -Expack.security.enabled=false
```